# How to update a column with information from another table

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a table defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE employees 
    (employee_id    INT(6),
     email          VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL);
```

and another one defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE personne (
    nopers          NUMERIC(6)  PRIMARY KEY,
    courriel        VARCHAR(40));
```

I'd like to fill the column "courriel" from table "personne" with the corresponding "email" from table "employees", based on corresponding "employee_id = nopers", and add "@technissimo.fr" to all emails.

I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
UPDATE personne
   SET courriel = CONCAT(employees.email, '@technissimo.fr')
 WHERE employees.email =
       (SELECT email FROM personne JOIN employees ON employee_id = nopers);
```

Can someone provide me with elements of answer on this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column `email` followed by the `WHERE` and `SET` clauses should belong to the `personne` table, those issues yield errors.

The query might be rearranged in the syntax like the below one with no need of subquery while still keeping the existing matching condition `ON employee_id = nopers` :

```
UPDATE personne 
  JOIN employees
    ON employee_id = nopers
   SET courriel = CONCAT(email,'@technissimo.fr')
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/MTeLkShO)</kbd>